# Too many arguments provided using params keyword with NUNIT in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Hello I'm writing some unit tests for a WPF application using NUNIT framework and I'm facing this **problem**:

I write my *positive* test cases like that:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldNotThrowException_TestCases
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new string[] { "", "first test argument name" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(new string[] { "test string", "first test argument name" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(new string[] { "first", "first name", "second", "second name", "third", "third name" });
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like that:

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldNotThrowException_TestCases))]
public void ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldNotThrowException (params string[] args)
{
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => ArgumentChecker.ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull(args));
}
```

The signature of the method to test is:

```
public static void ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull (params string[] argsAndNames)
```

The error I receive from Visual Studio when I run the tests is:
**Too many arguments provided**

I've tried to add a first parameter like I'm doing in other tests and its works! but the parameter remains unused.

This is the code used with that extra parameter:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldNotThrowException_TestCases
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(null, new string[] { "", "first test argument name" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(null, new string[] { "test string", "first test argument name" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(null, new string[] { "first", "first name", "second", "second name", "third", "third name" });
    }
}

[TestCaseSource(nameof(ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldNotThrowException_TestCases))]
public void ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldNotThrowException (Type expectedExceptionType, params string[] args)
{
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => ArgumentChecker.ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull(args));
}
```

I have other 53 tests with this structure of TestCaseSource currently working perfect.

How can I get rid of that extra parameter to get a clean code?

Thank you.

**Extra info**:

This is how my *negative* test cases look like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldThrowException_TestCases
{
    get
    {
        // Empty list
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentNullException), null);
        // List with odd number of elements
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { null });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { "" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { "test string" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { null, "first test argument name", null });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { "", "first test argument name", "" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { "test string", "first test argument name", "other" });
        // List with even number of elements
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentNullException), new string[] { null, null });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { null, "" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentNullException), new string[] { null, "first test argument name" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentNullException), new string[] { "", null });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { "", "" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentNullException), new string[] { "test string", null });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentException)    , new string[] { "test string", "" });
        yield return new TestCaseData(typeof(ArgumentNullException), new string[] { "first", "first name", null, "second name", "third", "third name" });
    }
}

[TestCaseSource(nameof(ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldThrowException_TestCases))]
public void ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull_ShouldThrowException (Type expectedExceptionType, params string[] args)
{
    Assert.Throws(expectedExceptionType, () => ArgumentChecker.ThrowExceptionOnAnyStringNull(args));
}
```

Comment: If you remove `params` from your test method's parameter definition, do you still get the same error?

Comment: @weichch yes, same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
yield return new TestCaseData(new object[] { new string[] { <string array elements> }})
```

The issue was `object[]` is assignable from `string[]`, so your `string[]` was parsed as each element being one separate parameter not the whole being one single parameter.